# How do I use multiple ngrok accounts on the same workstation?

Tags: networking, tunneling, ngrok

The config file of `ngrok` allows only a single `authtoken` line, and all resources available to you as a user (e.g., reserved hostnames) are based on the account associated with the authtoken.

If you have multiple ngrok accounts--for example, a professional (work) account and a personal account--and you want to use them with different projects, your only option is to add `--config secondary_filename.yml` to the command-line arguments to make use of another config.

How can you use your environment manager to switch to another ngrok account based on environment variables?

I am a Python user, so my use case applies mainly to `virtualenvwrapper`/`workon`, but this can probably equally apply to other environment managers (Ruby bundler?)

Answer (score 8):

you can specify a config file

https://ngrok.com/docs#config-location

my config was in ~/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml

i simply created a different config file ~/.ngrok2/myapp.yml

copy your other authtoken in there. and then to start it, use this command:

`ngrok http 3000 --subdomain=mysubdomain -config=myapp.yml`

Comment: Works but I had to put full absolute file name in double quotes

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you compile ngrok 1.7 and use it as you like without restrictions.

Source
https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/

Tutorial compiling:
https://www.svenbit.com/2014/09/run-ngrok-on-your-own-server/

Answer (score 0):

Until ngrok implements environment-variable-based configuration, you can achieve this in virtualenvwrapper by doing the following. I'm assuming the name of your project is MYPROJECT.

1. Create a second config file with your personal account. I will name this config file `ngrok-MYPROJECT.yml`. Set the value of `authtoken` to the account token for your account which is associated with MYPROJECT.
2. `chmod +x ~/.virtualenvs/MYPROJECT/bin/postactivate`
3. Edit the postactivate script you just edited, and add the following code:

```
ngrok () 
{
    command ngrok "$@" --config=$HOME/.ngrok2/ngrok-MYPROJECT.yml 
}
```

When you run workon again, `ngrok` will now be the shell function above. Running ngrok will execute the alternate config file you created in step 1.